# How generic is working in get() of ArrayList

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to develop my custom ArrayList class which will work in the same way as java.util.ArrayList does.
I am okay with resizing and other things.I am stuck when trying to get my object from my ArrayList. At the time of calling `add(T data)` it is fine to add in `Object[index]`.But when I am trying to `get(index)`, at that time I need to cast the object to of type T.In java.lang.ArrayList they are not doing any type cast.

Can someone put some light?

```
transient Object[] elementData;
E elementData(int arg0) {
   return this.elementData[arg0];
}
public E get(int arg0) {
  this.rangeCheck(arg0);
  return this.elementData(arg0);
}
```

How `elementData()` is converting Object type to E type?

Comment: `transient Object[] elementData;` should be `transient E[] elementData;`

Comment: if I will use transient E[] elementData; I can not create array of type E. Creating new E[size] will give compilation error since E has not any memory size.
Or again type cast will require.

Answer (score 2):

They certainly do cast `elementData[index]` to `E`:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
E elementData(int index) {
    return (E) elementData[index];
}
```

called by:

```
/**
 * Returns the element at the specified position in this list.
 *
 * @param  index index of the element to return
 * @return the element at the specified position in this list
 * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {@inheritDoc}
 */
public E get(int index) {
    rangeCheck(index);

    return elementData(index);
}
```

Comment: I have not seen any type cast or @SuppressWarnings in java.lang.ArrayList .java source code

Comment: @Afsar based on the method argument names in the code you posted, it looks like that code is not the original JDK java code.

Comment: Oh! got it they are  type casting.
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  E elementData(int index) {
         return (E) elementData[index];
  }
Thanks @Eran

Answer (score 1):

While you can cast before returning, it's worth just declaring your array as `E[]`, which will eliminate the need to cast:

```
transient E[] elementData;

E elementData(int arg0) {
    return this.elementData[arg0];
}
```

In addition to making the code cleaner, this also makes it clear to other developers that `elementData` is not meant for any data type other than `E`.